# Remove the original variables after converting into dummy variable by dummy.data.frame

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have a dataset having multiple categorical variables and did the conversion through `dummy.data.frame` function in dummies package.

It seems that I have the original columns also being kept in my output data frame. Is there any option in dummy.data.frame command to remove these originals columns so that i can have only dummy ones for converted ones?

Ex: *I wanted to drop Gender and keep only Gender.Female and Gender.Male columns in the output data frame...*

My code is:

```
my_loan_data.conv <- dummy.data.frame(my_loan_data[,-1],sep = ".")
```

Before conversion, this shows the output of the data frame having categorical variables..

```
'data.frame':   614 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Loan_ID          : chr  "LP001002" "LP001003" "LP001005" "LP001006" ...
 $ Gender           : Factor w/ 3 levels "","Female","Male": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Married          : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Dependents       : Factor w/ 5 levels "","0","1","2",..: 2 3 2 2 2 4 2 5 4 3 ...
 $ Education        : Factor w/ 2 levels "Graduate","Not Graduate": 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Self_Employed    : Factor w/ 3 levels "","No","Yes": 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ ApplicantIncome  : int  5849 4583 3000 2583 6000 5417 2333 3036 4006 12841 ...
 $ CoapplicantIncome: num  0 1508 0 2358 0 ...
 $ LoanAmount       : num  128 128 66 120 141 267 95 158 168 349 ...
 $ Loan_Amount_Term : num  360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 ...
 $ Credit_History   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ Property_Area    : Factor w/ 3 levels "Rural","Semiurban",..: 3 1 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 ...
 $ Loan_Status      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
```

After conversion, this shows the output of the data frame having dummy variables:

```
'data.frame':   614 obs. of  26 variables:
 $ Gender.                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Gender.Female          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Gender.Male            : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Married.               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Married.No             : int  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Married.Yes            : int  0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Dependents.            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Dependents.0           : int  1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Dependents.1           : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ Dependents.2           : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Dependents.3+          : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ Education.Graduate     : int  1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ Education.Not Graduate : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Self_Employed.         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Self_Employed.No       : int  1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Self_Employed.Yes      : int  0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ApplicantIncome        : int  5849 4583 3000 2583 6000 5417 2333 3036 4006 12841 ...
 $ CoapplicantIncome      : num  0 1508 0 2358 0 ...
 $ LoanAmount             : num  128 128 66 120 141 267 95 158 168 349 ...
 $ Loan_Amount_Term       : num  360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 360 ...
 $ Credit_History         : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 ...
 $ Property_Area.Rural    : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Property_Area.Semiurban: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ Property_Area.Urban    : int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ Loan_Status.N          : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ Loan_Status.Y          : int  1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 ...
```

Comment: Looks like your original variables are removed. That's how `dummy.data.frame` works...

Comment: Original factor columns are removed. In your case you have blank levels.

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate the problem with a small example:

```
# example data
df1 <- data.frame(x = as.factor(1:3),
                  y = as.factor(c(10:11, "")))
df1
#   x  y
# 1 1 10
# 2 2 11
# 3 3   

str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ x: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3
#   $ y: Factor w/ 3 levels "","10","11": 2 3 1

dummy.data.frame(df1, sep = ".")
#   x.1 x.2 x.3 y. y.10 y.11
# 1   1   0   0  0    1    0
# 2   0   1   0  0    0    1
# 3   0   0   1  1    0    0
```

Notice, the `"y."` column, this is not the original column, but the `""` level of `y`.

Now, do I need to keep the blanks or not for analysis is another question.